# Disqus - subscribing author

Tags: disqus

How is it possible to subscribe the page/post/article author to new comments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This blog post shows a pretty simple sollution:

http://wpdailybits.com/blog/notify-post-author-for-new-comment-disqus/45

Making use of the wp_notify_author function:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_notify_postauthor

That is if you are using WordPress of course.

Answer (score 0):

In case the question was in the context of WordPress + Disqus:

It's possible to solve the issue as described above by "hacking" the Disqus plugin; the bad part in doing so is that you'll break your upgrade path. In other words, any time you upgrade the Disqus plugin, you'll have to re-apply your hack (manually). And what if you manage multiple WordPress sites using Disqus? You get the point.

So to circumvent the problem of breaking your upgrade path, I've created a plugin for notifying post/page authors of Disqus comments. Works at least with up to WordPress 4.0 and Disqus Comment System (WP plugin) version 2.80.

You'll find the plugin here: https://wordpress.org/plugins/disqus-notify-content-author/