# How can I notify content creator of new Disqus comment on her page?

Tags: disqus

I have a site with user profile pages, that users can add content to, e.g. Anne.

Other users (e.g. Bob) can comment on these pages using Disqus.

When a Bob comments on Anne's page, I'd like to notify Anne of the new comment.

Currently Disqus emails the site moderator to notify the new comment. Can it be made to notify Anne as well?

I'm not using Wordpress (see related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4645373/disqus-subscribing-author) for discussion when using WP), this is a Django site.

I've seen that you can get a [Javascript callback](https://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/466258-capturing-disqus-commenting-activity-via-callbacks) from Disqus, which I could use to trigger an API call to my backend to send a notification email. But if Disqus can send notifications directly itself I won't need to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can, however it's a very manual process. This also requires that the author have a Disqus account and has enabled email notifications from Disqus.

Through the disqus admin tool, click on "Discussions" tab.  On this page you can set the thread/article author to a valid disqus user. Disqus will send notification to the author whenever someone comments.

Comment: Thanks for this - I'll mark as correct. This was why we binned Disqus!