# Django: How to add notification system to django disqus infrastructure?

Tags: python, django, disqus

I am new to Django and Recently i have integrated disqus commenting system to my Django Blog Application and now i want to develop notification infrastructure. I need two features :

1) Whenever a user comments , admin should be notified

2) Whenever user replies some comment, the commented user should get notification

For comments i have used disqus so i don't have any model/table created.
So how can i send notifications, can anyone please help me. how can i achieve this ? Correct me if i m following wrong method.Any suggestions are highly appreciated

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I notify content creator of new Disqus comment on her page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30187465/how-can-i-notify-content-creator-of-new-disqus-comment-on-her-page)

Comment: yes quite similar, this solution is useful for 1st feature that i mentioned in above question, thank u :)